# How to add GPAC(MP4Box) library to Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, mp4box

I am using Qt 5.11 and Mac OS (High Sierra). Trying to add GPAC (MP4Box), I compile the library downloaded from Git and then include its path in the `.pro` file like this:

```
LIBS +=   -L"/Users/stellar/Desktop/gpac/bin/gcc"
LIBS +=   /Users/stellar/Desktop/gpac/include
```

Then I include a header file in `main.cpp`:

```
#include<gpac/avparse.h>
```

Doing that I get the following error:

> "/Users/stellar/Desktop/gpac/include/gpac/configuration.h:163: error: "Unknown target platform used with static configuration file"

How to fix that?

Comment: Can you look at that line in GPAC's headers and work out why it's being hit? I'd guess it expects a number of #defines based on platform or things it's detected during configuration that it doesn't have.

Comment: It opens a configuration.h #define GPAC_CONFIGURATION "(static configuration file)" and this file defines all common macros for libgpac compilation
  except for symbian32 which uses .mmp directives

Comment: OK. If you look at [line 103](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/blob/master/include/gpac/configuration.h#L103) then it looks like you're supposed to have GPAC_CONFIG_DARWIN defined when building on Mac OS, and it looks like the configure script is supposed to set this up. Are you linking it from the build tree? It's possible that only gets set up if you `make install` it somewhere else first.

Comment: It works by defining DEFINES += GPAC_CONFIG_DARWIN in .pro file. Thank you @Rup